# The guide to X window system

Tags: documentation, x11, xorg

The X window system (and its popular implementation X.org) is amazing and complex too - client server model, forwarding the display to other systems, support for wide array of devices, primitive drawing functions. Moreover, the many ways to configure.

However there is no definitive guide to it which can teach it hands on. Can you please suggest any?

Comment: What kind of guide do you need?  Since you're posting on SO, I assume it's a development guide, but what are you trying to accomplish?  Give us some more detail so we can give you a more detailed response.

Comment: Yes I am expecting a development guide. Which can help me create lower level graphics like widgets, making a networked gui, making tools for X. An of course learning all this should also include learning about X too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend the HOWTOs from the Linux Documentation project, specifically [The X Window User HOWTO](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/XWindow-User-HOWTO/) and the [X Window System Architecture Overview HOWTO](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/XWindow-Overview-HOWTO/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

You may want to have a look at XCB for a fresh start into low-level Xorg developing:
http://xcb.freedesktop.org/

Answer (score 0):

You could try getting your hands on a copy of [X Window System: The Complete Reference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1555580882)  by Robert W. Scheifler and James Gettys

Comment: I think it's too old, esp. after they have a new C binding now called XCB: http://xcb.freedesktop.org/

Answer (score 0):

X.Org published [The X New Developer’s Guide](http://www.x.org/wiki/guide/) on their website last year.   It's not a long, in-depth guide, but a high level overview of the architecture and pointers to where
to find out more about specific parts of the graphics stack.